# 18.04: How can udev rule RUN script access network

Tags: networking, udev

I have an udev rule that downloads a file when a USB device is plugged in:

```
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="cafe", MODE="0660", GROUP="root", SUBSYSTEM=="usbmisc", RUN+="/home/me/udev-net.sh"
```

The script does a simple wget:

```
#!/bin/sh
wget -o /tmp/wget.log -O /tmp/index.html http://www.google.com
```

This works well on Ubuntu 16.04, but on 18.04 wget fails to resolve www.google.com - after triggering the script /tmp/wget.log contains:

```
--2019-08-19 14:49:43--  http://www.google.com/
Resolving www.google.com (www.google.com)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address 'www.google.com'
```

If I add an entry '172.217.23.164 mygoogle' to /etc/hosts, the resolve succeeds, but then wget blocks in socket connect(), and after some time the wget process is killed.

Is there some way of allowing this in Ubuntu 18.04, so that behavior is the same as on 16.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, this behavior is the same udev, trigger for short time just enough to configure new device, and it is run in a confined environment.

I would recommend a higher level script that run at user level, like Python/pyudev.

**Reference:** `man udev`

> Note that running programs that access the network or mount/unmount
>   filesystems is not    allowed inside of udev rules, due to the default
>   sandbox that is enforced on    systemd-udevd.service.

**Update:**

Another possible approach is using a `systemd` unit, like in this example:

```
storage:
  files:
    - path: /etc/udev/rules.d/01-block.rules 
      filesystem: root
      mode: 0644
      contents:
        inline: |
          ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="block", TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}="device-attach.service"
systemd:
  units:
    - name: device-attach.service
      contents: |
        [Unit]
        Description=Notify about attached device

        [Service]
        Type=oneshot
        ExecStart=/usr/bin/echo 'device has been attached'
```

Source: [CoreOS - Using systemd and udev rules](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/using-systemd-and-udev-rules.html#container-linux-config-example)

**Note:**

- I'm surprised that `systemd` which run as root allowed to connect directly (`wget`, `curl`, ...) and download files. Better to watch and verify, from where and what you are downloading. Even key sign them, if required.

Comment: Ah, good eye! This passage is indeed in the 18.04 udev(7) man page, but not in the 16.04 one. So the sandbox has been tightened since 16.04. A workaround that seems to work is to use at(1) to schedule the actual script.

Comment: @Weston, yes that one option, I added another one using `systemd`. I didn't try it and not sure if it has same timing behavior  (short processed only)  like in udev-RUN.

Answer (score 0):

`man udev`

> Note that running programs that access the network or mount/unmount filesystems is not allowed inside of udev rules, due to the default sandbox that is enforced on systemd-udevd.service.

Try a bypass with `atd` (only 256kB):

```
sudo apt install --no-install-recommends at
sudo systemctl enable atd
sudo systemctl start atd
```

Then replace

`RUN+="/home/me/udev-net.sh"`

with

`RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo /home/me/udev-net.sh | at now`"

---

`man at`

> at and batch read commands from standard input or a specified file which are to be executed at a later time, using /bin/sh.

The `atd` daemon runs your script in the future (now, with `at now`) in a different context from `systemd-udv` and gets around the network restriction. This is still working in Ubuntu 20 / Debian 11 in 2023.